# Remove asterix from column field to plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the below table from wikipedia, but I can't plot it due to the asterix. I can't work out what to do to remove the asterix, as I have even tried increasing the column width read, but the problem is in wikipedia

```
Year    Team    GP  GS  MPG FG% 3P% FT% RPG APG SPG BPG PPG
0   1984–85 Chicago 82  82  38.3    0.515   0.173   0.845   6.5 5.9 2.4 0.8 28.2
1   1985–86 Chicago 18  7   25.1    0.457   0.167   0.840   3.6 2.9 2.1 1.2 22.7
2   1986–87 Chicago 82  82  40.0    0.482   0.182   0.857   5.2 4.6 2.9 1.5 37.1*
3   1987–88 Chicago 82  82  40.4*   0.535   0.132   0.841   5.5 5.9 3.2*    1.6 35.0*
4   1988–89 Chicago 81  81  40.2*   0.538   0.276   0.850   8.0 8.0 2.9 0.8 32.5*
```

Comment: `data['RPG'] = data['RPG'].map(lambda x: float(x.rstrip('*')))` for each of the nasty columns.

Comment: or `data['RPG'] = data['RPG'].str.replace('*', '', regex=False).astype(float)`